# How to deduce return type of each function (on derived class) stored in a container

Tags: c++, function, lambda, return-type, variant

I would like to get return type of each function stored in a container. I have tried std::any and std::variant but i couldn't figure this out. Details below:

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public: virtual void test() { }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public: virtual void test() { }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public: virtual void test() { }
};

int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::function < Base(void)>> b;

    b.push_back([&]() { return Derived1(); });
    b.push_back([&]() { return Derived2(); });
    b.push_back([&]() { return Base(); });

    std::shuffle(b.begin(), b.end(), std::default_random_engine {});

    for (auto fn : b)
    {
        // Here I would like to reach the derived classes from "fn" somehow and use it like "new Derived1"
        //decltype(fn)::result_type ----------> this gives me Base only but i want the derived as well
    }

}
```

Comment: The return type of all of these functions is `Base` -- that is what it is declared as in the type of `b`.  The fact that your lambdas are creating an object of a derived type is irrelevant -- the return value with be "sliced" and converted into a `Base` in all cases.

Comment: This feels like an X, Y problem. Why exactly do you want to do this? You are circumventing the in built dynamic dispatch system, and there is maybe a better solution for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox To simplify some super complex system with minimal effort possible.

Comment: @Kitiara That is not really a specific enough reason. Why are you doing this, instead of using virtual functions the way they are designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this two different ways.

First way:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<Base& ()>> b;

    b.push_back([]() -> Base& { static Derived1 d1; return d1; });
    b.push_back([]() -> Base& { static Derived2 d2; return d2; });
    b.push_back([]() -> Base& { static Base b; return b; });

    std::shuffle(b.begin(), b.end(), std::default_random_engine{});

    for (auto& fn : b)
    {
        if (auto derived1_ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(&fn()))
        {
            derived1_ptr->test();
            Derived1* var = new Derived1(*derived1_ptr);
            var->test();
        }
        else if (auto derived2_ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(&fn()))
        {
            derived2_ptr->test();
            Derived2* var = new Derived2(*derived2_ptr);
            var->test();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Second way:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<std::shared_ptr<Base>()>> b;

    b.push_back([&]() { return std::make_shared<Derived1>(); });
    b.push_back([&]() { return std::make_shared<Derived2>(); });
    b.push_back([&]() { return std::make_shared<Base>(); });

    std::shuffle(b.begin(), b.end(), std::default_random_engine{});

    for (auto fn : b)
    {
        if (auto derived1_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived1>(fn()))
        {
            derived1_ptr->test();
            shared_ptr<Derived1> var = std::make_shared<Derived1>(*derived1_ptr);
            var->test();
        }
        else if (auto derived2_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived2>(fn()))
        {
            derived2_ptr->test();
            shared_ptr<Derived2> var = std::make_shared<Derived2>(*derived2_ptr);
            var->test();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of `fn` is `std::function<Base()>`, thus the result of calling `fn()` is always a `Base`.  It doesn't matter that the lambdas those `std::function`s wrap return other types.  Those return values are used to initialize an object of type `Base`.

Remember, in C++ polymorphism only works with references and pointers.  While a `Base&` or `Base*` can refer to a `Derived1` object, a `Base` object doesn't refer to anything.  It *is* a `Base` object and it can never be anything else.

If you want polymorphism you need your functions to return pointers:

```
int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>>> b;

    b.push_back([&]() { return std::make_unique<Derived1>(); });
    b.push_back([&]() { return std::make_unique<Derived2>(); });
    b.push_back([&]() { return std::make_unique<Base>(); });

    std::shuffle(b.begin(), b.end(), std::default_random_engine {});

    for (auto fn : b)
    {
        fn()->test();  // Will call the correct overridden test
                       // depending on the runtime type of the
                       // object pointed to by the returned unique_ptr
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not quite what i'm looking for, thanks for trying anyway